# Percent character replaced in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I'm sending a string using POST method as `"%100"` and it becomes `"0"`. I believe this is because they're being treated as encoded, but they're not.

Is there anyway to cancel this while still keeping security high, as this seems be caused by `Security->xss_clean()` and `Common remove_invisible_characters()`

Comment: In your `/application/config/config.php` is `$config['global_xss_filtering']` set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`? If it's set to `TRUE` and you're using `xss_clean` again, that might be what's double-encoding your input.

Answer (score 3):

Just look for the remove_invisible_characters() function defined in the CodeIgniter system/core/Common.php which is called by the function CI_Input::_sanitize_globals(). It is responsible for the cleanup of certain escape sequences starting with "%". I prefer to override the input class to disable the automatic sanitization of the globals.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the rawurldecode function, you could create your own MY_Security class that you can then use to override the xss_clean function. Maybe use PHP's rawurlencode function before calling the parent parent xss_clean function. Something like this:

```
<?php

class MY_Security extends Security {

    function MY_Security() {
        parent::Security();
    }

    public function xss_clean($str, $is_image = FALSE) {
        $str = rawurlencode($str);
        return parent::xss_clean($str, $is_image);
    }

}

?>
```

That will encode the value so that when it's decoded by the parent function, you'll have the original value you submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is nothing to do with CI or even PHP, but with your HTTP request.

Lets say I make a POST request that looks like this:

```
POST /path/to/file HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
User-Agent: Bob the browser/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 25

name=Dave&percentage=%100
```

What you are probably expecting is for `$_POST` to look like this:

```
Array
    (
        [name] => Dave
        [percentage] => %100
    )
```

But, in fact PHP will (correctly) decode it as this:

```
Array
    (
        [name] => Dave
        [percentage] => 0
    )
```

This is because `%10` is a valid url encoded string, and will be translated to the non-printable and in this context meaningless ["Data Link Escape" character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_escape_character#DLE), [ASCII 0x10](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In order to get the result you expect, the request needs to be like this:

```
POST /path/to/file HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
User-Agent: Bob the browser/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 27

name=Dave&percentage=%25100
```

So the value you actually send in the POST body is `%25100`. This will be correctly decoded as `%100`.

Comment: Hi, I've found that it's not actually about my HTTP request which is already url encoded and instead it's about Codeigniter's Security class, which is calling `rawurldecode()` for POST data. Have you any idea about would removing `rawurldecode` cause any security vulnerabilities in the system?

Comment: This happened to me too, and I chose to be lazy in this case by double-encoding. Now when CI tries to get in the way it ends up with single-encoded which is what I wanted.