# Stop CodeIgniter from incorrectly decoding URL-encoded content

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode, urldecode

By default, CodeIgniter blocks %27 (') from appearing in URLs. I have commented out the entire $config['permitted_uri_chars'] directive as a result. However, when I am now parsing part of the URL as a method argument that contains %27, or any other URL encoded portion, CodeIgniter converts it into a plain ?, before I can even run rawurledcode() on it. How can I stop it from doing this? We're using CI v1.7.x.

Here is some simple code to show it:

In the "Program" controller:

```
function test($parameter)
{
    echo $parameter;
}
```

Then we load http://example.com/program/test/o%27clock, and we get:

```
o?clock
```

I expected `o'clock` or at least `o%27clock` which I could just rawurldecode() with to get `o'clock`.

**UPDATE: Unfortunately, I was wrong. It was not being caused by CodeIgniter. Rather, the presences of suhosin was doing the substitution.**

Comment: please check this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8727050/2605821)

Comment: I already did to no avail.

Comment: You have commented the $config['permitted_uri_chars'] uncommenting it and adding the(') character would help i guess.

Comment: Hello @SOnali is right you can check in your config file and put this :- $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '?&=a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't CodeIgniter. It was suhosin.