# Codeigniter XSS Filtering ignores % sign

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, xss, urlencode

I have a search page on my website (built with CodeIgniter) that accepts a URL-encoded query string, like http://somesite.com/search?q=123. I want the contents of the parameter `q` to be displayed on the search page. The problem is, when I call `xss_clean()` on the value of the parameter (either while reading the query string or when outputting it), it converts any existence of a percentile character into its equivalent URL-encoded character. For example, `?q=100%25%20500`, which stands for the search string `100% 500` gets printed as `100P0`, because the XSS filtering logic of CodeIgniter appears to interpret `% 50` as `%50` (ignoring space), which translates to the character `P`, following HTML encoding rules. So my question is, what can I do to both allow the character `%` in my searches as well as have it XSS-filtered?

Here's my code fragment, if it helps to understand the problem better:

```
<?php 

$s = $this->input->get('q', FALSE);
echo "<p>You searched for $s</p>"; //this will show '100% 500'

$this->load->helper('security');
$t = xss_clean($s);

echo "<p>You searched for $t</p>"; //this will show '100P0'
```

Comment: There was a issue on github already: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5125

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percent character replaced in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725872/percent-character-replaced-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @miken32 I saw that, but there isn't an answer marked on that list. Which of the answers posted there would you recommend?